# Convert List of dictionary to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

input

```
values = [{'name': 'mike', 'age': '20'}, {'name': 'tom', 'age': 34}, {'name': 'kate', 'age': 99}]
```

output expected

output

```
values = {{'name': 'mike', 'age': '20'}, {'name': 'tom', 'age': 34}, {'name': 'kate', 'age': 99}}
```

Comment: dict can't hold another dict as a key but you have to convert into string.

Comment: The output you want is not valid in python.

Comment: The output shown above would syntactically represent a set of dictionaries. However, it is not valid to have dictionaries as members of set. Only immutable objects can be members of a set. The title of the question suggests that a dictionary is wanted, so there is probably a mistake in the syntax, but a similar problem would arise if trying to have dictionaries as keys of another dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The output you wanted has a **set** containing dictionaries. Since sets cannot hold dictionaries, we can convert the dictionary into tuples, and then we will use a set to hold these tuples.

For example, if we have:

```
values = [{'name': 'mike', 'age': '20'}, {'name': 'tom', 'age': 34}, {'name': 'kate', 'age': 99}]
```

We can do:

```
{i for dict in values for i in dict.items()}
```

This results to:

```
{('age', '20'),
 ('age', 34),
 ('age', 99),
 ('name', 'kate'),
 ('name', 'mike'),
 ('name', 'tom')}
```